# Network Driver failing after every reboot

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, network-adapter

I have a windows 8.1 machine. Every time I boot this system, without uninstalling the network adapter and scanning for any hardware changes in device manager it doesn't get the internet access. This happens after every single boot and is very miserable. Someone please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there Arunachaleshwar K! Did you try updating windows? If not, then try this:

Step 1. Go to your start menu and press Restart whilst holding the shift key
Step 2. Once it boots into the advanced options menu, click on Refresh Computer (NOTE: You will need to back up all the installers for the programs you have as it will uninstall every program on your computer). 
Step 3. press OK and wait around 1 hour (sometimes more) for the process to finish.

Now you should be able to update the driver.

Comment: Alright. Let me try it right away